# setting an option value empty in a dynamically changing select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I modify this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/nn83qf3y/

so that the '--None--' selections are outputted as

```
<option value="">--None--</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="--None--">--None--</option>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't put much time into your question, So here's a simple fix.

```
if(programs[i][1] == '--None--') {
    var opt = new Option(programs[i][1],'' );
}else{
    opt = new Option(programs[i][1]);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option